# Тег video/audio  не работает под Safari

Tags: html5, safari

Подскажите, пожалуйста, под какой формат нужно перекодировать видео/аудио, чтобы оно запускалось в сафари?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/video
http://habrahabr.ru/post/104591/

Comment: <video autoplay loop  id="bgvid">
        <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
        <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    </video>

Вроде все так как в статьях. но не работает.. в чем еще кроме формата может быть дело?

Comment: Напоминаю, что у шизанутого сафари видео/аудио запускается только в один поток, т.е. если нужно проиграть более одного ресурса, то вновь запущенный прибьет предыдущий, может, в этом ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari не поддерживает WebM, но поддерживает H.264